# Receive socket data on a keep-alive connection python

Tags: python, sockets

Sockets in python are slow and to my knowledge that's because how data is received. This *CAN* be solved considering libraries like PyCurl, Requests etc exist. Narrowing down the problem you'll see that it comes from adding the bytes received from the socket into a byte-string or similar (some form of concatenation).

Obviously ping to the server and all the other factors that do not relate to code can play a huge role in your program being/performing slow. browsing many articles/stack overflow posts you see all types of solutions yet I see none for keep-alive. Most of these solutions read until EOF which doesn't work for keep-alive connections.

```
def read_socket_data(socket):
    data = b""
    while True:
        try:
            data+=socket.recv(4096)
        except: #socket timeout
          return data
```

This is the best way i can come up with to read data from a keep-alive connection in python. This is obviously not the best or even a good solution considering the benchmarks. On average, it takes around .25 to send and recv data on a socket yet on libs like pycurl it is much faster taking around .10 seconds.

My question is: how can I appropriately receive data on a socket that is being kept alive by the user?

Comment: If a message is routinely shorter than your recv size 4096 then inevitably the timeout will determine the delay on recv. Otherwise Can you be more specific what you mean by “slow”? Maybe when “idle” you could receive in smaller chunks or with shorter timeout and adapt to the traffic flow?

Comment: "slow" as in pycurl and other libraries that have more overhead are performing better and recieving faster

Comment: No, that’s far too vague. Are you comparing apples with oranges? Being unhappy with “something” is unlikely to get a non-opinion based answer. Voting to close.

Comment: I think the problem here is a failed understanding of what a TCP socket provides: it is only a byte stream. Any message semantics (i.e. where the end of the message is) needs to be provided by the application protocol and needs to be adhered by both client and server. Thus when one side knows where the message will end it will not need to wait - it will just read as much as necessary and return the message. That's the way its done with HTTP, as used for example by curl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question but the receiving byte you put there is too large.
Traditionally, we use socket.recv(1024). I think thats why yours is slower

Comment: would this just not mean more recv calls though?

Comment: Yes but so what?

Comment: more recv calls means more string concats which if you read my problem you would know that this is the problem

Comment: I don’t ‘know’ that is the problem: you haven’t provided any evidence just a subjective claim.